Why does $\lim_{a\to-\infty}\lim_{b\to\infty}(b^2-a^2) = \infty$?
In my attempt to figure out $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{x}{dx}$, I accidentally solved it the "wrong" way and discovered Cauchy principle value.
I did: $\lim_{a\to\infty}\int_{-a}^{a}{x}{dx} \longrightarrow \lim_{a\to\infty}\frac{x^2}{2}\bigg|_{-a}^{a} \longrightarrow \frac{1}{2}(\lim_{a\to\infty}(a^2-(-a)^2) \longrightarrow \frac{1}{2}(\lim_{a\to\infty}(a^2-a^2) \longrightarrow \frac{1}{2}(\lim_{a\to\infty}(0)=0
$
I then checked my calculator and it said the integral in undefined, I checked online on integralcalculator.com and it said it was divergent, but 0 is it's Cauchy Principle Value. I now know not to take two endpoint limits at the same time, but along the way I found something weird. There's two ways to take $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}$ integrals.
One is with a double limit: $\lim_{a\to-\infty}\lim_{b\to\infty}\int_{a}^{b}{f(x)}{dx}$
The other is taking two integrals: $\lim_{a\to-\infty} \int_{a}^{c}{f(x)}{dx}+\lim_{b\to\infty}\int_{c}^{b}{f(x)}{dx} \space \big|c\in(a,b)$
In the two integral case, the first integral = $\infty$ and the second = $-\infty$ thus $\infty - \infty$ which is indeterminite. Great! I get that part. I also get the CPV case where $(a^2-(-a)^2)=(a^2-a^2)=0$
What I don't understand is the double limit case where $\lim_{a\to-\infty}\lim_{b\to\infty}\int_{a}^{b}{x}{dx} \longrightarrow \lim_{a\to-\infty}\lim_{b\to\infty} \frac{x^2}{2}\bigg|_{a}^{b} \longrightarrow \frac{1}{2}(\lim_{a\to-\infty}\lim_{b\to\infty}(x^2\bigg|_{a}^{b})) \longrightarrow \frac{1}{2}(\lim_{a\to-\infty}\lim_{b\to\infty}(b^2-a^2)) \overset{?}{\longrightarrow} \frac{1}{2}(\infty)=\infty
$
Why does $\lim_{a\to-\infty}\lim_{b\to\infty}(b^2-a^2) = \infty$ here?

Because if you fix an a then $\lim_{b\to \infty}b^2-a^2=\infty$ so $\lim_{a\to -\infty}(\lim_{b\to \infty}b^2-a^2)=\lim_{a\to \infty} \infty=\infty $. Notice how if you do the other way around you get $-\infty$ this is one of the reasons that we have to be very careful when you deal with not integrable functions

Yeah, if you want $a,b$ t9 go to infinity "at the same time," you have to write $$\lim_{(a,b)\to(-\infty,\infty)}.$$

(Principal value.)
